# Ansible ec2.py doesnt return all ec2 instances in the AWS account, it returns only the instances created in public subnets

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible-inventory

Trying to run ec2.py with Ansible dynamic inventory and have added the parameters 
destination_variable = private_ip_address
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address

in the ec2.ini file. gave executable permisisons for ec2.py and when I run ./ec2.py it returns only the ec2 instances in public subnets. There are another 2 instances in private subnets and those are never displayed. How would I use the ansible dynamic inventory agaisnt the ec2 instances in private subnets?

Answer (score 0):

in your `ec2.ini` file, just add this in order to get the private ip of the instance(s):

```
  vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address
```

Comment: that value is already set in the ec2.ini file. But when I run the ec2.py it lists only the instances which are created in public subnets it doesnt show any instances which are created in private subnets. Not sure what I am missing here